# NullReference exception when casting a layer into IGxFile Interface

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in, nullreferenceexception

I'm doing a simple test of a tool that uses a dockable window in an ArcGIS Desktop Add-In. I have a button that opens the window which will be the form that interacts with my other classes. I'm trying to access the maps and layers of an mxd but when debugging I get a NullReferenceException saying my layer object is not set to an instance of an object. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
namespace DockableExportTopoTool
{
    public class LaunchButton : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    {
        protected override void OnClick()
        {
            UID dockableWinUID = new UID();
            dockableWinUID.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.DockableWindow1;
            IDockableWindow dockableWindow1 = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockableWinUID);
            dockableWindow1.Show(true);
        }
    }
    public partial class DockableWindow1 : UserControl
    {
        Site site;
        public DockableWindow1(object hook)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Hook = hook;
        }
        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            site = new Site();
        }
    }
    class Site
    {
        private IMxDocument mxdoc;
        private const string quadsLayerFilePath = @"G:\USGS 24k Map Sheets.lyr";
        public Site() 
        {
            mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
            map = mxdoc.FocusMap;
            SetLayerReferences();
        }
        private void SetLayerReferences()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
            {
                IGxFile gxFile = map.Layer[i] as IGxFile;
                if (gxFile.Path == quadsLayerFilePath)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(gxFile.Path);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The gxFile object is raising the exception, right now I'm just displaying a MessageBox to show whether I've accessed the layer I need.

ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 C#.NET 4.0

Comment: Why are you using `IGxFile`? Seems like `IFeatureLayer` would make more sense.  That way you could cast `IFeatureLayer.Featureclass` to `IDataset` and figure out the path from there.

Comment: Just a quick way to get the file name for now I guess, I tried using IFeatureLayer but I'm getting the same NullReferenceException that I was getting for IGxFile. The point is I don't understand why I'm getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the api help file for the [IGxFile](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#igxfile.htm) interface it shows the classes that implement the interface. Layer returned by your `map` object is not a class that can implement the interface IGxFile.

The clue is the "Gx" bit, interfaces that have a "Gx" in their name tend to be interfaces for navigating file systems/workspaces, primarily within ArcCatalog or the browser panel in ArcMap.

So you are pointing `gxFile` to a class that cannot use it. As @KirkKuykendall points out you should be doing it via IFeatureLayer as you are obtaining *Layers* from the map not *datasets* from their source which IGxFile is expecting.

So in VB you would use something like

```vb
dim pFL as IFeatureLayer
pFL = map.layer(i) 'QI ILayer into IFeatureLayer
dim pDS as IDataset
pDS = pFL.FeatureClass

' Assumes dataset is a geodatabase featureclass
debug.print pDS.Workspace.PathName & "\" & pDS.Name
```